# How to store single name after face is recognized instead of saving the name repeatedly?

Tags: python, excel, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

im trying to store name from the frame, it does store the name but does it repeatedly i want the script to only store the name once whenever the face appears[this is the code[this is the result , i want to store the data single time whenever the face is recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS6Ji.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOdrJ.jpg)

i tried writing the lines of code out of the loop but that doesnt worked

Comment: You probably need to post more of the code so we can help. Lines posted now do not indicate why the name is written multiple times.

Comment: Also, [please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.